# Setting the AVAudioSession category in AppDelegate.m

Tags: objective-c, avaudiosession

So I hate to have to ask this question but I've spent a fair bit of time searching through Apple's documentation and Google with no avail. I'm simply trying to set the AVAudioSession category for my app ONCE, when the applicationDidFinishLaunching. I have an app that plays an audio stream and I would like it to continue playing when the app enters the background, so I'm trying to use the Playback category. Here is my code for AppDelegate.m :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Set AudioSession
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&sessionError];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];

// create window and set up navigation controller
[window addSubview:myNavController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}

# pragma mark -
# pragma mark AVAudioSession Delegate Methods 
- (void)beginInterruption {
}
- (void)endInterruption {
}
- (void)endInterruptionWithFlags:(NSUInteger)flags {
}
- (void)inputIsAvailableChanged:(BOOL)isInputAvailable {
}
```

With this code, the audio fades out anytime I hit the home button, putting
the app in the background. Any help is much appreciated, I hope that it 
is a quick fix type of answer for anybody who has done this before.

Answer (score 2):

First add the `UIBackgroundModes` key to your Info.plist file if you haven't done already.
More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW14).

If you have done that already, which framework do you use to play your media?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help Irene. You are pretty much right with your answer except I just wanted to provide the steps that were necessary for it to work for me. I read the apple documentation that you posted and for some reason it left these important details out:

1. When you add the UIBackgroundModes key in the .plist file, you have to make it an array.
2. The value for Item 0 of the array should be audio.

Of course your app should also take care of setting its audio session category in combination with setting this key.