# Send local notification when AVAudioSession route changes - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, local, avaudiosession

I am trying to send a local notification when the AVAudioSession route changes. 
There is an NSNotification called routeChangeNotification. I was able to set that up to send a notification but it only works if the app is in the foreground.
How can I set up routeChangeNotifcation to send a local notification to the user even when the app is in the background when it is called?
I looked into scheduling notifications and I found calendar based/ time based but how do I set up routeChangeNotifcation to be the trigger?

Comment: I saw an answer that iOS 7 it wasn’t possible unless you have something playing in the background. Anything new for iOS 12 or 13?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246853/ios-avaudiosession-route-change-notification-in-background